# Vba Macro to save file on folder

Tags: vba, excel, pdf, macros

I'm starting to learn how to work with VBA Macros and I'm in a point that a can't move on, So I have an excel workbook with some user and pass from a website, in my macro a read that values and navigate to that website using IE, after the login a want to download a pdf file, that file is generated after pressing a button

HTML on that button:

```
<input class="tB" value="Emitir" onclick="javascript:obterFormulario()" type="button">
```

VBA to open pdf in a new window

```
objIE.Navigate "javascript:obterFormulario('','')"
```

I already try to use URLDownloadToFile but my pdf dont have a url or i cant find it 
If you guys can help me I really appreciate

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is not really possible as far as I'm aware.  The PDF is being opened using a browser plugin, and isn't really subject to manipulation through VBA in the way you are using the IE Object in your code.  I could be wrong, but I'm not aware of any way to manipulate a PDF Viewer plugin through this form of VBA.